# Jquery Random Array Delete

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, random, numbers

```
var items = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];
function bigger(){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        a = [Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)+1];
        scale(a);   
    }   
}
function scale(number){
    $("#inner"+number+"").delay(100).transition({scale:1},300);
    items.splice(number,1);
} 
bigger();
```

here is my code ı try to delete numbers and use until finish array  and i want to do it 1 by 1

Comment: Replace the `for` loop with `while(items.length > 0)`, or your loop will stop before the array is empty. Remove the `[]` from `a = [Math...` - You're creating an array with one element and passing that array to `scale()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006480/randomly-select-value-form-array-and-delete-this-value-from-array

Comment: P.S. `delay()` only applies a delay to the animation queue on the individual element, so all of your elements will be processed at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need the index of the number in the array for `splice()`, not the string itself:

```
items.splice( items.indexOf(number), 1 );
```

It would probably be easier to just shuffle the array and pop of the last value to get a random array index, and at the same time removing it from the array:

```
var items = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"];

function scale(){
    var number = items.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random();}).pop();
    $("#inner"+number+"").delay(100).animate({opacity:1},300, function() {
        scale();
    });
} 

scale();
```

not sure where the `.transition()` method comes from, but guessing it has a callback ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcJn4/2/)

Comment: thank you very much its work so fine and transition is http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ transform jquery easyly for every browser thnx work fine like what ı want

Comment: everytime it gives same order i want to diffirent orders everytime :(

Comment: @UğurOruc - My bad, seems I messed up the random function, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
items.splice($.inArray(number, items),1);
```